# Convert inregular obejct to sipmle object

Tags: javascript, dictionary, reduce

I wan to convert irregular object ({{}, [] ...}) to an object consisting only of simple objects

I have this:

```
{
    "mname": "u1",
    "tab": [
        {
            "sname": "u2",
            "intab": [
                {
                    "l": 1,
                    "m": 3
                },
                {
                    "l": 2,
                    "m": 3
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            "sname": "u2",
            "intab": [
                {
                    "l": 1,
                    "m": 3
                },
                {
                    "l": 2,
                    "m": 4
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

but I want something like that:

```
{
    "mname": "u1",
    "tab": {
        {
            "sname": "u2",
            "intab": {
                {
                    "l": 1,
                    "m": 3
                },
                {
                    "l": 2,
                    "m": 3
                },
            }
        },
        {
            "sname": "u2",
            "intab": {
                {
                    "l": 1,
                    "m": 3
                },
                {
                    "l": 2,
                    "m": 4
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Generally, convert everything to objects in one main object

I suspect that this can be using the reduce function but in this case, because it is not a regular array of {key: value} objects, I can't handle it

Comment: you can not have an obejct without a name ...

Comment: what is the **]**

Comment: I can, e.g. from webapi